# xmodmap: Super modifier negates Mode_switch modifier when pressed together

Tags: manjaro, i3, xmodmap

Running Manjaro with i3wm.
I mapped my <kbd>Caps</kbd> key to Mode_switch modifier with `xmodmap`. I am using it to turn <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> into arrow keys, and a few other combinations.

Pressing <kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> works as intended (<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> are registered).

However, when I press together with <kbd>Super</kbd> key, the Mode_switch modifier seems to be negated: <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is registered as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> instead of <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

This is a problem as <kbd>Super</kbd> is my i3 mod key, and I'd like to use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Caps</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>S</kbd>/<kbd>D</kbd> to change focus.

This is my xmodmap output:

```
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock      
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        Mode_switch (0x42),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c
```

Comment: Hi @Mereketh. What do you mean by "supper key"? A Super key refers to several different keys throughout keyboard

Comment: @Goro I'm referring to the Windows key in standard US layout

Comment: Thanks! just to be sure that I understand your issue correctly. Let's say that `caps+w` are functioning as an `up arrow` because you mapped them using `xmodmap`. What is the problem when you click `win key+w`?

Comment: @Goro `win+w` is registered as `win+w`, as it should, and triggers an i3 shortcut. The problem is when I hit `win+caps+w`: I would expect it to be registered as `win+↑` since I mapped `caps+w` to `↑`, yet `win+w` is issued and so caps is for some reason ignored.

Comment: Have you tried to press Caps first, then the rest of the keys? I have the same issue when I first e.g. ctrl then Mode_switch